# Bar chart in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar chart in python using the following code:

```
prop_all = p_dead_men, p_men_first ,p_men_second ,p_men_third, p_dead_women, p_dead_child

%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 0.8
index = len(prop_all)
x = [u'Men', u'M-Ist', u'M-IInd', u'M-IIIrd', u'W', u'CH']
ind = np.arange(len(prop_all)) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title("Proportion of dead passengers by category")

plt.bar(ind, prop_all, width, color="blue")
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.show()
```

the output I get is missing the first x value completely and hence the histogram legend only shows the last 5. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, add this code here before **set_xticklabels(x)**:

```
ax.set_xticks(ind)
```

Or add an extra empty ticklabel:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([""]+x)
```

---

The reason is that your ax has a negative xtick. It seems to be something that the barplot creates. Look at this variable here:

```
ax.get_xticks()
```

Which returns:

```
array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
```